# selinux setting for outgoing psql connections from apache

Tags: centos, selinux

os: centos 6

currently i have enabled selinux to Permissive for the server, i want it to be set to Enforcing but at the same time selinux should be disabled for outgoing psql connections from apache..

i have set this for apache

```
chcon -R -h -t httpd_sys_content_t project/
```

but postgres communication from apache fails, disabling selinux makes it work...

any idea what parameters are for postgresql in apache..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
```